# Export a specific region of leaflet map to png

Tags: leaflet

I'm not sure if what I'd like to do can be done or not. I'm building a leaflet based app to track aircraft performing search and rescue patterns. The country is divided up into predefined grids, and these grids are used by the pilots to fly their track. The scanner in the backseat is survey the ground below looking for any sign of a downed aircraft.

What I'd like to be able to do is to print a copy of the map that is bound by the 4 points of the rectangle at a specific zoom level so it fits within an 8.5x11 sheet of paper. Examples I've seen all use a centerpoint, but I need to define the 4 corners, see what zoom level will fit on a page, and then make a print grid function available to users of the app.

Is this possible?