# Export a specific region from self hosted WMS

Tags: leaflet, wms, export

I have a question regarding the export function in leaflet. I‘m hosting a WMS Server, based on a SQL Database. This database is filled with images. Is it possible to export the full resolution images in a specific area / „frame“ to PNG directly from the database?

2018 someone asked something similar but there was no answer.
[Question from 2018](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278139/export-a-specific-region-of-leaflet-map-to-png)

Comment: Leaflet itelf can't do this, but there are some Leaflet plugins for that, see: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#printexport

Comment: One of the points of having a WMS service is that one can manually craft a WMS request for a specific area. I'm unsure if OP is sure about the DB hosting raster images, in which case it'd be best to just pull them directly instead of going through WMS and risking a resolution change.

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.